# ob_end_flush() suddenly exits the PHP script

Tags: php

Working on a shared web server used by other developers and designers. Processing XML documents. The following code had always worked for me until the other day:

```
while (ob_get_level() > 0) { ob_end_flush(); }
```

Since then, whenever `ob_end_flush()` is reached, the script appears to die as if `ob_end_flush()` has an `exit()`. No errors are output even with error reporting/display_errors on. When commenting out the above line, the script will run fully, displaying script output only once the full script has run. `@ob_end_flush()` made no difference. `ob_get_level()` is `1`. `var_dump`ing `ob_end_flush()` would also exit. Using CodeIgniter, but trying this code outside of the framework produced same result.

Is there a reason why `ob_end_flush()` would suddenly start causing the script to die each time? Are there any PHP settings I should be checking?

Comment: "*If the function fails it generates an E_NOTICE.*" - have you tried `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: have you tried `while (ob_get_level() > 0) { var_dump(ob_get_level()); ob_end_flush(); }` to see if it's failing/exiting on the first or last call to `ob_end_flush()`?

Comment: as for configuration: http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions - h2ooooooo I had tried that. HorusKol - I tried that and it said int(1) so it was managing to get the level out before exiting. Found the answer, I'll supply it below

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem at last - When my code seemed to start working outside of CodeIgniter, I checked CodeIgniter's index.php bootstrap file and came across this code that someone had added:

```
if (substr_count( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')){ 
      ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
} 
else {
     ob_start(); 
}
```

This was the cause.

Comment: Ah, how I love leaking abstractions.